# calling varargs method in python from var args method

Tags: python

I need to call this method

```
def overview(client, metrics_style, filter_api_style, overrides=None, zone_list=None, **kwargs)
```

from this method

```
def alerting_overview(client, metrics_style, filter_api_style, overrides=None, zone_list=None, **kwargs):
```

and I do so like this but the compiler complains that I can only pass in 5 arguments not 6

```
overview(client, metrics_style, filter_api_style, overrides, zone_list, kwargs)
```

How do I fix this so the kwargs is just passed seemlessly through?

thanks,
Dean

Answer (score 2):

You have to pass `**kwargs`:

```
overview(client, metrics_style, filter_api_style, overrides, zone_list, **kwargs)
```

Comment: lol, I tried that but the compiler was cryptic.  it 'was' working after all and I just had another secondary issue.  that was confusing.